# Are standoffs required if all holes rest on a raised part of the case?

Tags: computer-building

Are standoffs required if all holes rest on a raised part of the case?

The case I have is Thermaltake Versa H22 Plus
Motherboard is ASUS B350

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from looking at the marketing pictures for this case:
[image: Marketing shot showing moulded standoff]

It looks to me like the standoffs are built into the chassis. You should be able to confirm this with a soft-fit, place the motherboard on the standoffs and verify that the IO ports line up with the IO panel.

After reviewing some [YouTube footage](https://youtu.be/9x09mu987nc?t=201) of motherboard installations into this case, it looks like you can safely install your motherboard using only the built in raised portions of the chassis. There *are* also additional standoff screw mounts for motherboards that may require extra support.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I thought but was weary to exclude them.